# LED Board Driver Calculation

Tags: led, pcb, driver, surface-mount

If there is a Board that has 100 LED diodes however using different Diodes that have Different specs (Maximum Reverse Voltage, Max Wattage, Maximum drive current etc.) similar to a Quantum Board LED panel.

theoretically, how would you calculate the driver specs when determining what driver to use for the LED PCB board? and would the LED board even work?

**FOR EXAMPLE** lets say you are using this PCB board http://www.topledlight.com/red-copper-plate-pcb-circuit-board-100-spots-88mmx88mmx15mm-for-cree-xpe-xpe2-xpg-xpg2-xte-led_p1643.html

with 50 of these LEDs soldered onto them 
https://www.cree.com/led-components/products/xlamp-leds-discrete/xlamp-xhp35-2

23 of these in PHOTO RED and 23 in PHOTO BLUE (these have different "Typical Forward Voltage" 
https://www.cree.com/led-components/products/xlamp-leds-discrete/xlamp-xp-g3

and lastly 4 of these https://www.ledsupply.com/content/pdf/leds-semiled-uv_documentation.pdf

What Driver would you use, or how do you calculate the desired Driver output specs?

Will these LED Diodes work when soldered to the same board? will there be any type of bottle necking?(since the first diode listed is 13w and the others 6w)

I have a 20 Diode XP-G3 5000k and the driver that is compatible is a 100w PCB

**The specs read**

Power: 50W/100W
Model Name: CREE Xlamp XP-G3
Emitted Color:Cold White
Color Temperature:6000-6500K
DC Forward Voltage (VF): 30V-36Vdc
DC Forward Current (IF): 1500mA/3000mA
Maximum Pulse Voltage: 38Vdc
Maximum Pulse Current: 1700mA/3200mA
LED Viewing Angle: 115 degree
Size: (L)55*(W)40*(H)1.6mm
Usage:For flood light/high bay light/ House/Party/Architecture Decoration
The size is same as normal 100W LED,more birght and can instead of it.

**and i chose this driver**

https://www.ledsupply.com/power-supplies/mean-well-lpv-led-power-supply?gclid=CjwKCAjw2qHsBRAGEiwAMbPoDCfRLPvCJRTU6k42X-JfvpGUlxyPLmgIvWD7KKm0SthuQ_MGAroXFhoCD1UQAvD_BwE

Let me clarify. I am soldering a 100 diode quantum board using CREE LEDs and i want to know if the varying CREE Diodes will work properly when soldered to the same board (they are all 3.45 mm and fit on the board but that doesn't necessarily mean it will work efficiently.) I need to learn how to calculate and determine what driver to use and i was hoping someone here could help me.

Comment: Iteratively. Create a design, evaluate it, start over.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Different LEDs on a PCB](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/460001/different-leds-on-a-pcb) which was closed as unclear what you are asking. Please fix the original question rather than duplicate it. You can then delete this one to save the moderators a job.

Comment: If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. It was put "on hold" in order to allow you to improve it before people try to answer it. Do not create a duplicate question.